# Programmatically reading and changing elapsed time of music(iPod's media library)?

Tags: iphone, time, mpmusicplayercontroller, audio-player

I am creating a music application, much like the standard music app.  Now, I am befuddled on how they were able to read and change the elapsed time of a song using a UISlider.  How is it possible to read and change the elapsed time of a song?

Comment: After your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274475/detecting-if-music-is-playing), did you have a look at the documentation for `MPMusicPlayerController`?

Comment: Well, I looked and found nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications` on the `MPMusicPlayerController` and registering for `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notifications, you will receive periodic updates when the playback state has changed. In the handler for that notification you can then get the `currentPlaybackTime` from the `MPMusicPlayerController`.