# How can I check itunes player status in Iphone or Ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I create a game. and now I need to check itunes is playing or not. 
I will mute game background music when itunes is playing in background

In cocos2d, itunes will fade out when SimpleAudioEngine play.
And If turn on itunes backgroud, cocos2d's game will fade out bgm.

So need some code to check system status.

Comment: You mean iPod, not iTunes, right?

Comment: Answered here: [Detecting if music is playing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274475/detecting-if-music-is-playing)

Comment: **what have you tried?** because when you would have started to set up the `AVAudioSession` you should have got the answer to this question... It seems you haven't done anything yet.

Comment: yes, yes this code: if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) . thx your help.

Comment: all code here:#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying){
  NSLog(@"backgroud music is playing");
  return;
 }

Comment: You can answer your question and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

add mediaplayer.frameworks and import:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

then copy those code to needed place.

```
if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying){
    NSLog(@"backgroud music is playing"); 
    return;
}
```